# Validating read-only date field on multi-stage jquery form

Tags: jquery

How would I validate the "Third Step" on my multi-stage jQuery form?

It can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/xSkgH/22/

I want to prevent the user from going onto the next step without entering a value so ideally an error message would pop up if they try.

So far the field is **readonly** so the user cannot edit any entries but this alone doesn't prevent the user from completely skipping the step and carrying on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if `$('#datepicker').val()` is *falsy* in case you are sure your datepicker will always insert valid values:

```
if (!$('#datepicker').val()){
alert('no date!');                
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/28/

In case this gets a little more complex some time soon you might want to look at the **[jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)** that many people use.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works sorta well but still allows the user to carry on to the next step.

Comment: @CJS: yes, I just wanted to demonstrate how to check if there is a value, your menu seems rather complex so I didn't want to dig too deep.